# Renaming data frame columns using symbolic names from stored variables?

Tags: r

I am building a function that requires me to rename columns in a data frame, where the original column names are stored in a variable from user input.

```
#self$options$DV is a string identifying the column of interest, such as 'chosenvarname':    

DVlabel <- self$options$DV
```

However, the dplyr::rename function doesn't work when using this variable or its symbolic link:

```
df1 <-plyr::rename(df1,c(DVlabel='DV'))

df1 <-plyr::rename(df1,c(self$options$DV='DV'))
```

Even when DVlabel is set to equal a valid column name in the data frame, it still doesn't work

It only works properly when using the actual column name, which makes me think that this function doesn't work with symbolic links:

```
df1 <-plyr::rename(df1,c(OriginalColumnName='DV'))

Is there another way to use the column name identified in self$options$DV as the basis for renaming that same column to something else? 

Put differently, is there any way to rename a column using symbolic links to the column name that don't otherwise exist in the data? 

Alternatively, is there some way to construct a column reference, such as data$var1, where the "var1" component is extracted from some other variable (e.g., DVlabel or self$options$DV?)
```

Comment: Sorry about the last few lines being formatted as code. I wasn't sure how to get the $ characters to show up properly otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this by using the following to rename the columns:

```
colnames(df1)[colnames(df1) == self$options$DV] <- 'DV'
```